# Auto refresh wepage when source file changed

Tags: html, apache, webserver

I have been learning web development for some time and I have noticed on tutorials on youtube that when someone change source file (html, css, js) the webpage opened in browser is automatically refreshing. I have read something about live-reload but it's too complicated for me and there is no step by step tutorial.

I have found some similar questions, but the case is that refreshing happens by side of local server not the code editor or browser as is mentioned in questions that I found.

I'm using Apache as my local server. Sublime Text for writing a code and Ubuntu operating system.

Here is the video that shows what I am exactly trying to say.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q78u9lBXvj0
Npm and live-server doesn't work on my computer at all.

Sorry for my english, but I'm not a native speaker. I'm looking forward for your help.

Anyone knows anything?

Answer (score 2):

Install sublime web server using package manager ( or in your case continue to use Apache )

Use http://livejs.com/